# Create link on customer account BUT not last

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-account

I am making a question because I couldn't find a way to overcome that.I have made a link in the Account Dashboard but it comes last. How can I put it first?
I used before="-" but it doesn't change it.

```
> <customer_account>
>         <reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
>             <action method="addLink" >
>                 <name>trade</name>
>                 <path>tradedownloads/index/index</path>
>                 <label>Resources</label>
>             </action>
>         </reference>
>     </customer_account>
> 
>   <tradedownloads_index_index>
>         <update handle="customer_account" />      <reference name="my.account.wrapper" >
>         <block type="core/template" name="tradedownloads" before="-" template="tradedownloads/left.phtml"></block>            
>     </reference>
>     </tradedownloads_index_index>
```

That's the xml file i use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do with standard Magento functionality.

You need to rewrite block `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` methods `addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())` and `getLinks()`. Add parameter `$order` to `addLink` method. And do sorting by order in `getLinks`.

If you will do that in your xml file you can do something like this

```
<action method="addLink">
    <name>trade</name>
    <path>tradedownloads/index/index</path>
    <label>Resources</label>
    <urlParams></urlParams>
    <order>1</order>
</action>
```